# C# IEnumerable Retrieve The First Record

Tags: c#, .net

I have an IEnumerable list of objects in C#. I can use a for each to loop through and examine each object fine, however in this case all I want to do is examine the first object is there a way to do this without using a foreach loop?

I've tried mylist[0] but that didnt work.

Thanks

Answer (score 25, accepted):

(For the sake of convenience, this answer assumes `myList` implements `IEnumerable<string>`; replace `string` with the appropriate type where necessary.)

If you're using .NET 3.5, use the [`First()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.first.aspx) extension method:

```
string first = myList.First();
```

If you're not sure whether there are any values or not, you can use the [`FirstOrDefault()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault.aspx) method which will return `null` (or more generally, the default value of the element type) for  an empty sequence.

You can still do it "the long way" without a `foreach` loop:

```
using (IEnumerator<string> iterator = myList.GetEnumerator())
{
    if (!iterator.MoveNext())
    {
        throw new WhateverException("Empty list!");
    }
    string first = iterator.Current;
}
```

It's pretty ugly though :)

In answer to your comment, no, the returned iterator is *not* positioned at the first element initially; it's positioned *before* the first element. You need to call `MoveNext()` to move it to the first element, and that's how you can tell the difference between an empty sequence and one with a single element in.

EDIT: Just thinking about it, I wonder whether this is a useful extension method:

```
public static bool TryFirst(this IEnumerable<T> source, out T value)
{
    using (IEnumerator<T> iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            value = default(T);
            return false;
        }
        value = iterator.Current;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is mylist.GetEnumerator().Current equal to this? I'd like to know just for the sake of knowing.

Comment: I'm not sure if I like the extension method as its out parameter makes it less composable. I know that's the point of the method in this case but having something non-composable on a sequence seems wrong.

Comment: The result of this isn't a sequence though - it's only ever going to be a single element and a Boolean, so it would have to be at the end of the composition chain anyway. I think if you looked at places where you'd actually want this, it wouldn't be a problem. As you say, it's the point of the method.

Answer (score 3):

Remember, there may be no "first element" if the sequence is empty.

```
        IEnumerable<int> z = new List<int>();
        int y = z.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: In order to use FirstOrDefault(), you need to declare "using System.Linq;"

Answer (score 2):

If you're not on 3.5:

```
 using (IEnumerator<Type> ie = ((IEnumerable<Type>)myList).GetEnumerator()) {
     if (ie.MoveNext())
         value = ie.Current;
     else
         // doesn't exist...
 }
```

or

```
 Type value = null;
 foreach(Type t in myList) {
     value = t;
     break;
 }
```